# ASP._page_views_diagnostics_<page>_cshtml does not inherit from System.web.ui.page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got an asp.net application that is mixing in or slowly moving to mvc, but when accessed via routing `http://localhost:9490/razor`

I get `Type 'ASP._Page_Views_diagnostics_razor_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.UI.Page'.`

**Exception Details:**`System.Web.HttpException: Type 'ASP._Page_Views_diagnostics_razor_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.UI.Page'.`

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Type 'ASP._Page_Views_diagnostics_razor_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.UI.Page'.]
   System.Web.UI.Util.CheckAssignableType(Type baseType, Type type) +8864436
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp) +75
   System.Web.Routing.PageRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) +138
   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context) +8911880
   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e) +86
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +148
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

When accessed almost directly (without the .cshtml)

`http://localhost:9490/views/diagnostics/razor`

this was happening before I added a views or controllers folder to the project. previously it was `Pages/Diagnostics/razor` with `routes.MapPageRoute(null, "razor", "~/Pages/Diagnostics/razor.cshtml");`

Route configured is `routes.MapPageRoute(null, "razor", "~/Views/diagnostics/razor.cshtml");`

It works fine. the page itself is pure html outside of a single variable access to confirm server side razor code is firing.

```
    @{
    Layout = null;
    Page.Title = "Razor test";
}
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Razor rendering success</p>
<p>
IsPost=@IsPost
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? I mean get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

I could be off here : ) but - why are you using "MapPageRoute" in an MVC app, I believe that is meant for a web forms app. Use a controller and then MapRoute to your controller to then in turn go to your view. Nothing in the views folder is supposed to be directly addressable, in fact there's an entry in your web.config to specifically try to prevent this.

Comment: This is an asp.net web app, not an MVC app. MapPageRoute is for a razor page with no controller. This works with the direct path(non-routedPath) without a controller. Have not implemented controllers at all in this project.

Comment: hmmm.. why use only the "V" in MVC?n what do you gain?

Comment: it's not my plan to only use the V, my plan is to move this app over, but I can take baby steps that are non-intrusive to validate that they can live in harmony, and new coding can happen with V or full MVC if I can work out the kinks.

Comment: For example you're building a single-page app (SPA) on top of the AngularJS or similar framework. Then you don't need ASP.NET MVC views/controllers other than Web API. You may still want to map specific URLs to physical .cshtml files. But unfortunately .MapPageRoute() works only with .aspx pages :(

Comment: In that case what are you gaining? Use a simple html page with your applicable script otherwise you are circumventing several things to simply get a cshtml file which you as per convention shoudn't be addressing directly anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using WebPageRouteHandler, which you can get through the NuGet system. In answer to Adam's comment, you gain the ability route more complex url's such as those used by Backbone.js when accessing your RESTful server. It would be ridiculous to create a separate folder for every possible id in the database. You also gain the ability to organize your files differently than the way the url's are structured.